# python addition 2 digit number

Tags: python, binary

I'm studying algorithms. The exercise consist in put a number of 2 digits (between 10 and 99) and then do the addition of the two digits. I made it in python and it works, but my teacher said that there's another way to do it without the conversions that i'm using. Can you help me? Is there a better way? Thanks.

```
for i in range(5):
    add = 0
    num = input("Number: ")
    num = int(num)
    if num > 9 and num < 100:
        num = str(num)
        add = int(num[0]) + int(num[1])
        print("The addition of the two digits is: " + str(add))
    else:
        print("It is not a two digit number.")
```

Comment: what do you mean by conversions?

Comment: You could do it without the first conversion to `int` and back to `str`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think he meant:

```
(num // 10) + (num % 10)
```

With `num // 10` you perform an integer division with 10. But this is the first digit. With `num % 10` you get the remainder of the division, which is the second digit. For example:

```
>>> 67 // 10
6
>>> 67 % 10
7
```

The most succinct way must be:

```
sum(divmod(num, 10))
```

because `divmod` performs the integer division with 10 and finding the remainder at the same time. So with `sum` we get the sum of those two numbers. For example:

```
>>> divmod(67, 10)
(6, 7)
>>> sum(divmod(67, 10))
13
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations?

Comment: @edTarik Is it ok now?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, if I use my code as a programmer, am I doing it wrong? I know that a programmer must simplify things but what if I didn't know the best answer and made it in my own way, is it bad?
Thanks

Comment: Of course not. Becoming a good programmer is a process and a very good ingredient is to try solving the problems ourselves. The mistake would be if we don't allow ourself to study also other practices.

Comment: @alexprezmon You made it on your own and that's the essential in my opinion. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

```
rem = num%10
quotient = int(num/10)

sum = rem+quotient
print sum
```

I guess this should suffice.

Comment: Unless you're using the old Python2 version, num/10 will return a float, that's not what you want

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Edited it.